# Как убедиться, что динамический массив монолитен в памяти?

Tags: массивы, delphi, память

Всегда считал, что диспетчер памяти Delphi старается выделять под динамические массивы монолитные куски памяти.  Так ли это?

По нашей просьбе когда-то для нас создали API для Delphi 64. К прибору идёт DLL (без исходников, знаем, что часть расчётов написана на фортране, часть - выполняет прибор) с функциями, принимающими в качества параметров массив и его длину (в пятницу с коллегами был "глухой телефон", вот сейчас у меня перед глазами проект, непосредственно копирую из него).

```
type
  TTaxInputIntData = record
    len: int64;
    rsrvd1, rsrvd2:integer;
    rsrvd3:double;
    data:array of integer;
  end;

// универсальный массив для матрицы tSF:
// len - ранг матрицы
// data - матрица распределения, размер должен быть строго равен (len+2)*len, первый и последний столбцы - нулевые


  TStructureList = record
    rng: integer;
    rsrvd1, rsrvd2:integer;
    rsrvd3:double;
    data:array of byte;
  end;

// возвращаемые значения:
// rng: ранг матрицы таксономии
// размер data = rng*rng
// для корректной работы нужен монолитный массив data

procedure Init1(channel:byte); stdcall; external 'Delphi64TaxAPI.dll';

// обязательно к вызову. channel = 1..131, см. Руководство оператора, том 2, страницы 489 - 511
// 1..89 - расчёт на основании уже обработанных данных
// 90.. 131 -  должны быть загружены образцы (!!!)

function CreateTaxonomicDiff(value:TTaxInputIntData; out Structure:TStructureList):integer; stdcall; external 'Delphi64TaxAPI.dll';


// возвращаемые значения:
// 0 - отсутствуют значимые различия. Для поиска минорных различий используйте функцию CreateMinorTaxDiff
// 1 .. N (N <= len*len) - максимально возможное среднее отклонение в единицах tSF
// -1 - Det(sA) = 0, некорректная выборка
// -2 - некорректная матрица распределения
// -3 - суммарная длина векторов меньше, чем   (len+2)*len
```

Отмечено, что функция возвращает корректные результаты в 100% случаев, если SetLength для массива data вызывался лишь раз (т.е. данные были сразу помещены в массив и переданы в функцию). Например, так:

```
var
  matrix:TTaxInputIntData;
  err:integer;
  list:TStructureList; 

<...>

ar:=matrix.data;
SetLength(ar,len*(len+2));
for i := 0 to len+1 do
  for j := 0 to len-1 do
    if (i=0) or (i = (len+1)) then
      ar[j*len + i]:=0
    else ar[j*len+i]:= data[k];
matrix.len:=length(matrix.data);
err:=CreateTaxonomicDiff(matrix, list);
```

в `err` получаем положительные значения (кроме тех случаев, когда отличий нет, - тогда ноль), в `list` - девиации.
если же затем увеличить массив `data` и дописать в него хотя бы один вектор:

```
k:=length(ar);
SetLength(ar, k + len+2);
for j:=0 to len+1 do
    if (j=0) or (j = (len+1)) then
      ar[k+j]:=0
    else ar[k+j]:= data1[m];
```

, то с вероятностью 10-20% (со слов коллег) в `err` возвращается ошибка -3.
При этом, если создать новый массив и в него внести все данные, влючая новые:

```
k:=length(matrix.data);
SetLength(ar1, k + len+2); // ar1 - новый массив
for i:=0 to k-1 do
  ar1[i]:=matrix.data[i];
for j:=0 to len+1 do
    if (j=0) or (j = (len+1)) then
       ar1[k+j]:=0
    else ar1[k+j]:= data1[m];
matrix.data:=ar1;
```

, то ошибок не случается.

Понятно, что код переписали и используется второй вариант, но хотелось бы разобраться, почему возникает ошибка.
Было мнение, что массив может быть немонолитен после последовательного вызова SetLength, но вы меня разубедили :) Но в чём тогда может крыться ошибка?
К сожалению, поддержка со стороны разработчиков инструмента уже невозможна :(

Comment: На чём написана dll и какая у вас версия Delphi? Я бы рекомендовал проверить корректность описания функции: соглашение о вызове, типы параметров, выравнивание полей структуры.

Comment: @zed На фортране. Версия Delphi - 10.1, но тестировали и на более новых.  Функция описана вроде бы корректно (позже тогда добавлю её описание из модуля), структура, в которую передаются данные на возврат, - это обычный двумерный байтовый массив. Уточнил сейчас, разные ли ошибки (возвращается не ноль в этом случае), - нет: всегда возвращается -3 (размер массива меньше, чем переданный параметр len).

Comment: несколько странно видеть длл написанную на другом языке и с сигнатурами без `stdcall`

Comment: @teran stdcall там есть. В понедельник буду на работе приведу полное описание функции

Comment: С "монолитностью", кажется, все выяснили. Покажите, пожалуйста, точное определение функции, параметров (очень интересно узнать про `TStructureList`) и как Вы ее вызываете, включая действия с массивом, приводящие к ошибке. Если есть определения этой функции для других языков, то давайте и их.

Comment: А, увидел про FORTRAN. Функция описана неправильно, в других языках не существует параметра `array of integer`. Не нужно "разбирать Memory Manager по косточкам". Нужно правильно написать определение функции в Delphi.

Comment: Ваш вопрос на 99% изменился после редактирования, другими словами - до неузнаваемости. Вам стоило в таком случае задать новый вопрос, а не редактировать старый, т.к. все старые ответы, можно сказать, пошли в трубу!

Comment: @zed я ошибся только в двух вещах, описав по памяти проект, с которым работал очень давно: передача не непосредственно массива, а записи, содержащей этот массив, ну, и плюс stdcall.

Answer (score 6):

Массив монолитен по определению, а каждый раз, когда вы вызываете `SetLength`, он может менять своё местоположение в памяти.

Если вы передали функции указатель на свой массив, а затем изменили его размер, то очевидно, что у функции останется мусорный указатель и вероятно возникновение AV.

Соответственно, если вы передаёте свой массив куда-то во вне, то ни в коем случае, не должны изменять его размер, а так же необходимо позаботиться, чтобы он не был автоматически удалён из памяти, т.е. чтобы оставалась как минимум одна ссылка на массив, пока функция не отработает до конца.

Upd:

Внутри Delphi, динамический массив представляет собой вот такую структуру (картинка [отсюда](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html#dynarrays)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. это непрерывная область памяти, где располагается 2 служебных поля (размер массива и счётчик ссылок) и ваши данные. Служебные поля находятся по отрицательному смещению от указателя на массив. Соответственно, нет никакой разницы, сколько раз вызывать `SetLength` для массива - структура его всегда будет оставаться такой же. Единственное отличие, так это то, что местоположение в памяти, может меняться. Но это никак не влияет на процесс чтения/записи значений в него и не может приводить к каким-либо ошибкам.

Comment: Нет. Возможно, надо дополнить вопрос. Передача массива в функцию происходит финально, то есть затем с этим массивом никаких действий непосредственно в программе не выполняется. Собственно, после получения результата он более и не нужен.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Тогда, либо вы неправильно поняли предупреждение от автора функции, либо автор функции написал ерунду (мягко говоря). Массив - это указатель на область памяти (непрерывной), где лежат данные. По отрицательному смещению этого указателя хранится счётчик ссылок и размер массива. Вот и всё.

Comment: Вот и я всегда так считал. К сожалению, пока действительность опровергает моё мнение. Похоже, придётся разбирать Memory Manager по косточкам.

Comment: Смущает ещё и явное указание длины массива. Не проще ли обратиться по адресу - 4, чтобы взять ёё?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov У вас какая-то неправильная действительность. Это даже в документации написано: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Array_Types

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Ещё раз повторю: в Delphi массивы монолитные, элементы массива следуют один за другим, без пропусков на выравнивание и прочее.

Comment: были массивы кусками, весь код с арифметикой указателей для доступа к элементом рухнул бы у всех.

Comment: @teran Вы наверное имели в виду **"были бы"** :)

Comment: @zed очевидно, да 8)

Answer (score 3):

Функция из DLL не должна иметь такой прототип  - заметьте, что `data: array of integer;`  - **не** динамический, а **открытый** массив, прямых аналогов которому в других языках нет.

Параметр - открытый массив  на самом деле некая [хитрая структура данных](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html), обслуживаемая магией компилятора, так что такой аргумент умеет принимать  - из Дельфийского кода, конечно - и статические, и динамические массивы.

В данном случае он ещё и по значению передаётся, что для обработки больших данных не фонтан.

Поэтому нельзя рассчитывать на то, что функция с таким прототипом будет корректно работать (иногда везёт, видимо, из-за того, что указатель на данные идёт в начале).

Comment: 1. Когда мы покупали прибор, мы доплатили за API, выбрав при покупке именно модуль для Delphi.. 2. Видимо, именно поэтому у функции и есть параметр len: чтобы функция "знала", сколько элементов в массиве. 3. "Иногда" было "всегда", пока мы не стали хотеть большего, а именно на лету добавлять данные в массив из нескольких экспериментов. Но если тупо создать новый массив и в него внести данные, то ошибки ни разу не было, в отличие от варианта, когда массив дополняется. Какая-то магия...

Comment: Что тут сказать - создатели АПИ, вероятно, не подумали, что в Delphi означает такой синтаксис. Как я вижу из комментария к вопросу, этот прототип может быть приведён по памяти, и на самом деле там могут быть тонкие отличия от приведённого? А про монолитность тела массива zed совершенно прав.

Answer (score 3):

Попробую и я :).

Вы не можете передавать в DLL, написаную на FORTRAN-е или любом другом языке, (или получать оттуда) данные, которые в Delphi, объявлены как `array of something`. Откровенно говоря, такие типы данных не должны пересекать границы выполняемых модулей, даже если обе стороны написаны на Delphi. Исключение - компиляция с run-time packages, но это уже другая история.

Delphi-евские динамические массивы (как и open array параметры) настолько компиляторозависимые вещи, что рассчитывать на то, что они отобразятся на что-то адекватное в другом языке - сильно рисковать, как Вы уже и испытали. Когда оно работает, Вам просто везет.

К сожалению, Вы не привели "родной" декларации функции и типов данных, возможно, у Вас их нет. Также Вы не показали, как осуществляется вызов функции с Вашими данными, этот-то код у Вас есть?

Что такое здесь `matrix`, и какое значение у `matrix.data` перед этими манипуляциями:

```
ar:=matrix.data;
SetLength(ar,len*(len+2));
```

Какой смысл в присвоении `ar:=matrix.data;`, если сразу после него массиву назначается (новая?) длина и присваиваются значения всем элементам? При взгляде на такой код, меня начинают мучить подозрения, что люди не совсем понимают, что они делают.

---

Теперь о том, как нам со всем этим жить.

```
{$R-}

type 
  TIntegerArray1 = array[0..0] of integer;
  PIntegerArray1 = ^TIntegerArray1;

  TTaxInputIntData = record
    len: int64;
    rsrvd1, rsrvd2:integer;
    rsrvd3:double;
    data: PIntegerArray1;
  end;
```

*(Надеюсь, не ошибся с синтаксисом, писал прямо сюда.)*

Здесь будет больше работы с распределением/освобождением памяти, но это то, как следует делать такие вещи.

Comment: @MBo Это для первой структуры. Я уверен, что Виктору не нужно указывать на необходимость сделать то же самое и для второй.

Comment: А, пардон, упустил разницу

Comment: var matrix:TTaxInputIntData  просто создателю, видимо, удобнее работать так с массивом, а не через with, хотя и лишние телодвижения при этом

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Вы или автор кода похоже так и не поняли, что после вызова SetLength создаётся новый массив и в matrix.data остаётся мусор, до тех пор пока не будет выполнено присвоение `matrix.data := arr`.

Comment: @zed Хм, и вправду, я и не обратил внимания, делается ли обратное присваивание. Может, всё просто, и не везде это осуществляется...

Answer (score 0):

*Не является ответом. Могу удалить после того, как все прочтут. Просто комментарий такой длины и с кодом тяжело читать, а если напишу это в вопросе, всё станет ещё более запутаннее.*

Мне очень стыдно за свою невнимательность: я "подорвал" нескольких участников из-за неправильного, по сути своей, вопроса.
Как правильно указал @zed, всё дело было в том, что создавая новую переменную динамического массива `ar:=matrix.data`, тот, кто писал код, забывал затем выполнить обратное присвоение, т.е. `matrix.data:=ar`. Мне стоило прошерстить весь код и обнаружить ошибку самому. При этом matrix.len, как правило, стабильно увеличивали, из-за чего функция и возвращала "-3".

Вот откуда и возникли странные 10-20% возникновения ошибок: поскольку пакет существует достаточно давно, то студенты добавляли в него новые возможности, на разный лад обращаясь к библиотеке. И всё писали по-разному. Я не поленился связаться с бывшим студентом, кто писал именно этот код. Вспомнив, о чём речь, он удивился: "Я считал, что работаю с указателями, мне было лениво везде таскать имя структуры, а так - короче. Не думал, что в Delphi, присваивая один динамический массив другому, я создаю его заново. Странный язык, этот ваш Delphi". ("почему вместо этого не использовать `with`?" -  я не и спросил)

С другой стороны, не пригласи меня коллеги поискать, почему у них периодически возникают ошибки, и не решись я спросить совета у сообщества, вопрос бы не решился :)

Comment: Бывший студент ничего не понял. Не Delphi - странный язык, а он не знает (не знал?), как работать с указателями. Но, как писал Джоел Спольски в 2000-м году, когда SO с его политикой дружелюбия еще не было, "некоторые люди рождены без той части мозга, которая нужна для работы с указателями". То, что сделал студент, это все равно что полагаться на то, что `realloc` вернет указатель на тот же адрес, но кусок выделенной памяти станет больше. Я так понимаю, Вы не собираетесь переделывать динамические массивы на явное выделение памяти? Будем ждать новых вопросов про "монолитность" :).

Comment: @Igor Я "накосячил" и должен это осознать :) С другой стороны, я вижу, что то, что не должно работать, - работает (передача динамических массивов в стороннюю библиотеку). Я должен "выпить с этим пива" (так говорят чехи, и это, наверное, лучший вариант мультиязычной поговорки :) И да, если я снова буду тупить, я буду задавать вопросы. А то вы этого не ждёте :)

Comment: Увидел, как вызывается `CreateTaxonomicDiff`. Второй параметер как-то заполняется значениями (особенно `list.data`) перед вызовом? Или это полностью делается кодом в DLL?

Comment: @Igor ЕМНИП, байтовый массив заполняется нулями, поскольку делается вычитание матриц. Могу завтра уточнить, если это важно

Comment: @Igor Да, он заполняется нулямя. Почему, впрочем, мне никто не ответил

Comment: Хорошо. Я хотел убедиться, что память на него распределяется снаружи DLL. Я считаю, что правильно было бы использовать `var` (а не `out`) перед вторым параметром.